# How to Hide Irrelevant Data Results

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have a report that I generate weekly that shows contracts being expired or soon to be expired within 90-days.  The report works fine, however, the contracts or sites that are NOT out of contract or soon to be expiring are still appearing as headers on the report.  My question is, how do I ONLY show the sites expired and due to expire and not the other sites (headers, names, etc...).

```
SITE_INFO
===========================================================
SELECT  SITE.ID SITE_INFO_ID,
        "ORGANIZATION"."NAME" "CUSTOMER_NAME",
                "SITE"."NAME" "SITE_NAME",
                "CUSTOM"."VALUE" "MANAGER_NAME",
                "ADDRESS"."ADDRESSLINE1" AS "ADDRESSLINE1",
                "ADDRESS"."ADDRESSLINE2" AS "ADDRESSLINE2",
                "ADDRESS"."ADDRESSLINE3" AS "ADDRESSLINE3",
                "ADDRESS"."CITY" AS "CITY",
                "ADDRESS"."STATE" AS "STATE",
                "ADDRESS"."COUNTRY" AS "COUNTRY",
                "ADDRESS"."POSTAL_CODE" AS "POSTAL_CODE",
                "ADDRESS"."SITE_ID" AS "SITE_ID",
                "REGION_CODE"."ID" AS "REGION_ID",
            "REGION_CODE"."NAME" AS "REGION_NAME"
FROM     ORGANIZATION,
              SITE,
              CUSTOM,
              ADDRESS,
              REGION_CODE
WHERE SITE.ORGANIZATION_ID = ORGANIZATION.ID AND
       CUSTOM.SITE_ID = SITE.ID AND
       CUSTOM.NAME LIKE 'MANAGER NAME' AND 
       SITE.ID = ADDRESS.SITE_ID AND
       REGION_CODE.ID = SITE.REGION_ID AND
       SITE.IS_DELETED = 0


SYS_DATE
=============================================================
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') FROM DUAL


CONTRACT_INFO
=============================================================
SELECT CONTRACT_TYPE.NAME CONTRACT_NAME,
       CONTRACT.SITE_ID SITE_ID,
       CONTRACT.CONTRACT_INDEX CON_INDEX,
       TO_CHAR(CONTRACT.END_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') END_DATE,
       CONTRACT.ORDER_NO ORDER_NO,
       CONTRACT.PROJECT_NO PROJECT_NO,
       CASE WHEN CONTRACT.END_DATE <= SYSDATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FLAG
FROM CONTRACT LEFT JOIN
     CONTRACT_TYPE ON CONTRACT.CONTRACT_TYPE_ID = CONTRACT_TYPE.ID 
WHERE CONTRACT.SITE_ID = :SITE_INFO_ID
AND CONTRACT.END_DATE <= SYSDATE + 90
```

The SITE_INFO and CONTRACT_INFO data sets are linked, and the template is created in MS Word using BI Publisher.  Code is written in SQL in BI Publisher online.

Comment: Can you share the BI Publisher template that you are using which contains the problem?

Comment: @EdHayes3 Sorry for the basic question, but how do I upload a file on StackOverflow?

Comment: I think I figured out what you want and posted answer below. As for sharing a file, you can always post a public link to google drive, dropbox, or some other free file sharing service.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a little more than you need, but would work.

1. Repeat Site section for each site. Each section starts a new page.
2. Count number of expired contracts within site, with unique order numbers.
3. Only show site if number of expired contracts is more than zero.
4. Site content
5. Within site content, show count of expired contracts (optional)
6. Repeat contract section, only for contracts that are expired.

Assuming you have data structure:

```
EXTRACT/LIST_SITE_INFO/SITE_INFO/LIST_CONTRACT_INFO/CONTRACT_INFO
```

XML Like:

```
<EXTRACT>
    <SYS_DATE>2015-05-15 8:30:25</SYS_DATE>
    <LIST_SITE_INFO>
        <SITE_INFO>
            <CUSTOMER_NAME>Test Customer</CUSTOMER_NAME>
            <CUSTOMER_ID>123</CUSTOMER_ID>
            <SITE_NAME>Test Site</SITE_NAME>
            <LIST_CONTRACT_INFO>
                <CONTRACT_INFO>
                    <CONTRACT_NAME>Contract 123</CONTRACT_NAME>
                    <ORDER_NO>456</ORDER_NO>
                    <CONTRACT_ID>789</CONTRACT_ID>
                    <FLAG>1</FLAG>
                </CONTRACT_INFO>
            </LIST_CONTRACT_INFO>
        </SITE_INFO>
    </LIST_SITE_INFO>
</EXTRACT>
```

Template would looks something like this:

```
<?for-each@section:EXTRACT/LIST_SITE_INFO/SITE_INFO?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘V_EXP_COUNT’, count(xdoxslt:distinct_values(//LIST_CONTRACT_INFO/CONTRACT_INFO[FLAG="1"]/ORDER_NO)))?>
<?if:xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘V_EXP_COUNT’)>0?>
```

Site Section / Content

Number of Expired Contracts: `<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘V_EXP_COUNT’)?>`

```
<?for-each:LIST_CONTRACT_INFO/CONTRACT_INFO[FLAG="1"]?>
```

Expired Contract Section / Content

```
<?end for-each?>
<?end if?>
<?end for-each?>
```

Make sure there's no spaces/new-lines between the elements in the template.

Comment: Ed, thanks for the reply. However, I am a bit confused at the information provided. Are you saying that the template needs modifying or the Data sets/Data model?

Comment: I added some example XML for what I expected the data to look like. The other logic would be in the template.